# Uninstalling app: "App is part of the following app: ..." Why is that?

Tags: android, uninstallation, android-8.0-oreo

I realized that my self programmed app shows a strange dialog when I try to uninstall it:

[image: My App]

Normally if you try to uninstall any other app it says...

[image: Other Apps]

---

What have I done wrong?
Where do I have to change something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, now I accidentally found out why and when this happens:

If you change "android:label" of the Launcher Activity to a different name than the actual app name, the app name on the start menu of your device changes.

So if you then try to uninstall the app, it simply says what the displayed and what the real name (which is e.g. shown in the settings) is.

It's normal, many Google apps have the same message if you try to uninstall them.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
File >Settings >Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run
```

Turning off the Instant run, reinstall your apk and try to delete from phone

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn´t work, After I turned it off, I tried it by installing with Android Studio on my smartphone and by generating APK and installing it. Both didn´t work. Any more ideas?